# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0700ca

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a login fragment and want to replace the fragment after successful login.
I tried to replace the fragment inside the login fragment.

**First** I tried to call the following code inside the fragment (onActivityCreated,onCreateView,onStart)

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainframelayout, ReservationFragment.newInstance())
            .commitNow();
```

My **second way** was to try to call a activity method:

```
public void replaceFragments(Class fragmentClass) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.mainframelayout, fragment)
        .commitNow();
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.mainframelayout, LoginFragment.newInstance())
                    .commitNow();
        }
    }

    public void replaceFragments(Class fragmentClass) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainframelayout, fragment)
            .commitNow();
    }
}
```

**Activity xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/mainframelayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

The following error always came up:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.retrofit, PID: 15872
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07007c (com.example.retrofit:id/mainframelayout) for fragment
>   ReservationFragment{6e639e1} (59264633-2704-48d9-872d-551ef1142b68)
>   id=0x7f07007c}
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:305)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1816)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:297)
>           at com.example.retrofit.MainActivity.replaceFragments(MainActivity.java:33)
>           at com.example.retrofit.ui.login.LoginFragment$1.onClick(LoginFragment.java:54)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
>           at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15872 SIG: 9

I've tried many things, but I haven't found a solution.
I understand that the fragment may not have access to the activity xml, but why the second way not work I dont understand.

Comment: I didn't see any issues. You should provide more codes I think. The better way to replace a fragment is to capture the login in the activity by viewModel or any interface. Also, you can follow this link https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: I found out the problem is setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
If I call this (like onResume inside Activity) then is ok, if I just call in the onCreate then same error...Should I call     should I call    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity); multiple times?

Comment: No so just create your fragment in onResume(). But I highly recommend using the navigation component. It is simple and new.